# how to apply shadow on full object in threejs

Tags: three.js

i want to apply shadow on full object using threejs, if i rotate the object the shadow must be with the object, meaning that i want to apply the shadow for the hole object, i tried with `Spotlight`, but no luck i doesn't get any changes on my object, so here below is my code

```
light = new THREE.SpotLight( 0xffffff );
light.position.set( 200, 200, -200 );
light.castShadow = true;
light.shadowMapWidth = 1024;    // power of 2
light.shadowMapHeight = 1024;

light.shadowCameraNear = 200;   // keep near and far planes as tight as possible
light.shadowCameraFar = 500;    // shadows not cast past the far plane
light.shadowCameraFov = 20;
light.shadowBias = -0.00022;    // a parameter you can tweak if there are artifacts
light.shadowDarkness = 0.5;

light.shadowCameraVisible = true;
scene.add( light );
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to set `object.receiveShadow = true;` on the object on which shadows should be rendered ?

Comment: no @vincent,where i have to set this ?? thanks for the answer

Comment: you have to set this attribute on the object who will receive the shadow, like I said. You can set it directly after creating the object for example.

Comment: do you have an online example ? with jsfiddle maybe ?